# Generating Maven GAE Endpoints library and importing it into Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Maven Google App Engine Endpoints API in Java.  I compiled the JAR by following these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_client_library_for_android_using_maven).

I recently transitioned to Android Studios from Eclipse.  I'm trying to import the JAR into Android Studio. I added this line to build.gradle:

```
compile files('./libs/warAPI-v1-1.19.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
```

What other dependencies do I have to add to build.gradle?  I can't seem to find a list anywhere.

Comment: I dont know about maven but have you added  warAPI-v1-1.19.1-SNAPSHOT.jar externally and also in your libs folder.

Comment: The issue isn't importing it into Android Studios, the issue is the Maven generated GAE endpoints JAR requires additional dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Clicking the button `Sync Project With Gradle Files` should solve your problem:

> Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

If that fails, try running `Rebuild project`:

> Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: The issue isn't importing it into Android Studios, the issue is the Maven generated GAE endpoints JAR requires additional dependencies

Answer (score 0):

These are the dependencies I ended up adding:

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.18.0-rc') {
        // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android',
            version: '1.18.0-rc') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.google-play-services', module: 'google-play-services')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    }
    compile(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-gson', version: '1.18.0-rc') {
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    }
    compile(group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-android',
            version: '1.18.0-rc') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    }
    compile files('./libs/warAPI-v1-1.19.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')

    compile(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0-rc2')
}
```